# imagemagick resize error message

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

i used node js vesion 0.10.0

i don't know what's wrong

please help me

my cording content

```
    im.resize({
      srcPath: __dirname+'\\files\\1420783733353.jpeg',
      dstPath: __dirname+'\\files\\1420783733353_new.jpeg',
      width:   256
    }, function(err, stdout, stderr){
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('resized kittens.jpg to fit within 256x256px');
    });
```

error content

```
      if (err) throw err;
                     ^
Error: Command failed: Àß¸øµÈ ¸Å°³ º¯¼öÀÔ´Ï´Ù - -set


at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\works\mongodb2\node_modules\imagemagick\imagemagick.js:88:15)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:700:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:913:11)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Pipe.close (net.js:436:12)
```

Comment: Do you have imagemagic binary installed on your system ?

Comment: how does it install?

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows

Comment: i installed but same error

Comment: Just put the imagemagick in your path varible like this http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the imagemagic node module is not updated from quite some time and also as mentioned in their git page https://github.com/yourdeveloper/node-imagemagick

What i did to get the desired result

I followed the instruction on this page

https://github.com/aheckmann/gm

And using this code

```
var gm = require('gm')
, dir = __dirname + '/imgs'
gm(dir + '/original.jpg')
.options({imageMagick: true})
.resize(250, 250)
.write(dir + '/resize.jpg', function(err){
if (!err) {
console.log("this will be the resized image : resize.jpg" );
}})
```

will resize your image to 250 x 250

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem on Window 7.
I got helped, below page's AlexDisler comment.
https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-icon/issues/38

Windows already has a convert program.
So you must input full path of 'convert'.

> Open `imagemagick.js` which you will find in the `/node_modules/imagemagick/`

And change line 256

> exports.convert.path = "convert";

to

> exports.convert.path = "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q8\convert";

or whatever your ImageMagick install folder is.